# Configuration of proxy with x++

Tags: proxy, x++, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I have proxy in my entreprise, and I want to test code X++ to connect internet and send e-mail.

I don't know what I can do to configure proxy in dynamics ax or what line code X++ can I add to my methode :

```
void SendMail()
{

    System.Net.Mail.MailMessage             mailMessage;
    System.Net.Mail.Attachment              attachment;
    System.Net.Mail.AttachmentCollection    attachementCollection;
    System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient              smtpClient;
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress             mailAddressFrom;
    System.Net.Mail.MailAddress             mailAddressTo;
    str                                     Body;
    str                                     Subject;
    str                                     SMTPServer;
    str                                     FileName;
    str                                     psw;
    str                                     login;

    System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod      stmpDeliveryMethod;

    System.Net.WebProxy                     proxy;

    ProxyIPAddress                          proxyIPAddress;
    ProxyPortNum                            proxyPortNum;

    System.Net.Sockets.Socket               socket;

    System.Net.NetworkCredential            cred;
    ;


    login ="mylogin@gmail.com";
    psw="mypassword";

    mailAddressFrom = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mylogin@gmail.com","");
    mailAddressTo = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("mylogin@gmail.com","");
    Body = "<B>Body of the email</B>";
    Subject = "Subject line for the email";
    //SMTPServer = SysEmailParameters::find(false).SMTPRelayServerName;

    mailMessage = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage(mailAddressFrom, mailAddressTo);
    mailmessage.set_Subject(Subject);
    mailmessage.set_Body(Body);

    cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(login, psw);

    smtpClient = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
    smtpClient.set_EnableSsl(true);

    stmpDeliveryMethod = ClrInterop::parseClrEnum('System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod', 'SpecifiedPickupDirectory');
    smtpClient.set_DeliveryMethod( stmpDeliveryMethod);
    //smtpClient.DeliveryMethod()= System.net.mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network);
    smtpClient.set_UseDefaultCredentials(false);
    smtpClient.set_Timeout(20000);

    smtpClient.set_Credentials(cred); //.Credentials = cred;

    proxy=new System.Net.WebProxy();



    print 'On va envoyer! remarque : next msg est : "sa marche" ';

    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

    print 'sa marche';

    //////////////////////////////////////////
    CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();

}
```

---

For example i configure parametre of proxy in firefox or internet explorer to can connect internet ! i specifie ip 192.168.66.33 and port 1234 ! and in dynamics ax i can't do that !

in c# w edit web.config :

we Add this in our application's web.config file.

in dynamics ax what we can change ?!!

Rq :

For example i configure parametre of proxy in firefox or internet explorer to can connect internet ! i specifie ip 192.168.66.33 and port 1234 ! and in dynamics ax i can't do that !

in c# w edit web.config :

we Add this in our application's web.config file.

```
<system.net>

<defaultProxy>

<proxy proxyaddress="YourProxyIpAddress"/>

</defaultProxy>

</system.net>
```

in dynamics ax what we can change ?!!

Comment: Consider improving your question, as it is unclear. What is you goal? What is your problem? Any error messages? Proxy for what?

Comment: some one can see this link : i don't understand but i think this is the solution http://www.komkid.net/2010/01/axapta-firewall-config/

Comment: Your proxy setup in firefox or internet explorer is an http proxy, this is smtp. Are you sure this is what you want to do?

Comment: yes ! because this is the same proxy for http and smtp and ftp ...

Comment: not sure how to do this directly in x++, but you could write a dll or .net assembly in C# (you seem to know C# better) and the call that to send the mail? This way you can setup your proxy in C#.

Answer (score 2):

The link you posted (firewall-config) is to allow external access to the aos server, has nothing to do with your issue.

I haven't tested it myself (i have no proxy to test with) but have you tried adding the configuration section in the ax32.exe.config in the client bin directory (or if your code is executing on the server, the server bin directory)?